# Console error when visiting meta

Tags: support

This might be a temporary problem but I get this error in the firebug console when visiting the meta site. It says `WebSocket failed` and that Firefox can't connect to the server on `ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/`.

on this line:
`socket = new MozWebSocket(url);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We are testing web sockets on meta at the moment so you will probably see more debug messages in your console than normal.  These will go away in future builds - the main issue is why can't you use web sockets?  If you're using Firefox, switch to Chrome and try again.

Also try this test:  http://websocket.org/echo.html

Comment: !!!! websokets?! blasphemy!