# Authentication dialog on all SE pages

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting authentication prompt for sockets.ny.stackexchange.com on every page load?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124132/getting-authentication-prompt-for-sockets-ny-stackexchange-com-on-every-page-loa)

For the last couple of days, whenever I open a page on the SE network I get an authentication dialog that says "Enter username and password for http://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com". I'm running Firefox 10 on Windows XP.