# Having a problem visiting Stack Overflow over proxy in Firefox

Tags: support, firefox, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My corporate proxy doesn't support web sockets, which makes Stack Exchange a pain to use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130053/my-corporate-proxy-doesnt-support-web-sockets-which-makes-se-a-pain-to-use)

Every time I go to Stack Overflow with Firefox at my work (which has a proxy). I get this popup asking for "Authentication Required". However, I am able to visit every other site and I don't get this popup. Also, I can visit Stack Overflow via Internet Explorer or Google Chrome, and I don't get this popup. It's very inconvenient. How can this problem be fixed?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Npgfp.jpg]