# New questions are not shown automatically

Tags: support, questions, search

At home i like the new feature that new questions are displayed asynchronously. A link with the number of new questions is shown at the top. If i click it, the new questions will be loaded. They are also shown earlier compared to refreshing the page via <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL+F5</kbd>.

But it doesn't work at another computer, they are not shown at all. What can be the reason?

Note:

- i'm using Firefox in both (12.0)
- [my favorite link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#%20or%20LINQ%20or%20vb.net%20or%20asp.net%20or%20ado.net%20or%20tsql%20or%20sql-server%20or%20SQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because:

1. The version of FireFox you're running does not support WebSockets. The system does not offer backwards compatability for older browsers <sup>[citation needed]</sup>
2. You have a proxy/ firewall/ <insert another filtering device> in place which block WebSockets from been used (i.e. a spin-off of [My corporate proxy doesn't support web sockets, which makes Stack Exchange a pain to use](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130053/my-corporate-proxy-doesnt-support-web-sockets-which-makes-se-a-pain-to-use) or [Getting authentication prompt for sockets.ny.stackexchange.com on every page load?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124132/getting-authentication-prompt-for-sockets-ny-stackexchange-com-on-every-page-loa))

Comment: Sorry that i've left out the FF-version, edited my answer accordingly. I'm using FF 12.0 in both. Yes, you're right, i'm using google proxy here(http://www.google.com/xhtml). Thank you very much :)

Comment: Your citation is here: [What technology/framework is StackOverflow using to asynchronously update clients?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129499)